# Define a generic class in this case

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I'am using generic in C# 4.0. This is my code:

```
public class Class1
{
}

public class SubClass1 : Class1
{
}

public class Class2
{
}

public class SubClass2 : Class2
{
}

public class GenericClass1<T1, T2>
    where T1 : Class1
    where T2 : Class2
{
}

public class MyClass1 : GenericClass1<SubClass1, SubClass2>
{
}

// error here
public class GenericClass2<GenericClass1<T1, T2>>
    where T1 : Class1
    where T2 : Class2
{
}

public class MyClass2 : GenericClass2<MyClass1>
{
}
```

I got error when compile GenericClass2 "Type parameter declaration must be an identifier not a type". Anyone help me to rescue or find a solution for this case of generic. Thanks.

Comment: There is nothing we could work with here. You did not post your full code, you did not post what you want to achieve, you did not even post the error. You can do better.

Comment: Read my code, you will understand my purpose. You will get error when compiling. I need a help how to solve it when using generic

Comment: What makes you think I will open up VS and compile it for you, when you have the error right in front of you and could post it here?

Comment: Sorry. I don't know about nested generic, so hardly to explain. I want to use nested generic in my code, I need to find solution for this.

Comment: You need to find a solution but you cannot even adhere to basic SO standards like *actually posting the error message you get*. That's too bad. I'm out of here, good luck finding a solution to your problem.

Comment: I updated my question and include compiling error :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot use nested declarations in class definitions like this: `GenericClass2<GenericClass1<T1, T2>>`. You can use such code instead:

```
public class GenericClass1<T1, T2>
    where T1: Class1
    where T2: Class2
{
}

public class MyClass1 : GenericClass1<SubClass1, SubClass2>
{
}

public class GenericClass2<T1, T2, T3>
    where T1: Class1
    where T2: Class2
where T3:GenericClass1<T1, T2>
{
}

public class MyClass2 : GenericClass2<SubClass1, SubClass2, MyClass1>
{
}
```

Comment: This solution works. However, I must repeat class name 2 times. As you see, MyClass1 is using from SubClass1 & SubClass2 but we repeat it again in definition of MyClass2 -> why .net compile can't understand automatically :(

Answer (score 2):

You can also use like below -

```
public class Class1
    {
    }

    public class SubClass1 : Class1
    {
    }

    public class Class2
    {
    }

    public class SubClass2 : Class2
    {
    }

    public class GenericClass1<T1, T2>
        where T1 : Class1
        where T2 : Class2
    {
    }

    public class MyClass1 : GenericClass1<SubClass1, SubClass2>
    {
    }


    public class GenericClass2<U>
        where U : GenericClass1<SubClass1, SubClass2>
    {
    }

    public class MyClass2 : GenericClass2<MyClass1>
    {
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
public class GenericClass2<TGeneric, T1, T2>
where TGeneric: GenericClass1<T1, T2>
where T1 : Class1
where T2 : Class2
{
}
```